# How does lazy evaluation work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to functional programming and I want to undersatand how lazy evaluation works. I have the following functions:

```
nats = 0:(map (+1) nats)
test = foldr (\x y-> if x > 2 then 0 else x+y) 10 nats
```

And as far as I can tell, the first one gets the list of all natural numbers until it runs out of memory (but that never really happens, that I understand), and the second one is supposed to do exactly what? Test has inside a lambda calculus function that gets an x and y and returns 2 if x > 2 and x+y else, but is that supposed to mean that it will return 0 because x = 10? I'm a little confused. In that case, is nats really called for?

EDIT: 
Test returns 3, but now I'm really confused because I don't understand how.

Thanks and sorry if I'm making some rookie mistake, but I'm failing to understand how this works.

Comment: You simply have it backwards: `x` ranges over the elements of `nats`, which is used,  and `10` will be used only when the end of `nats` is met -- which means that `10` will never be used. The `foldr` computes `0+(1+(2+(0))` where the last 0 is due to `x=3>2` making the `if` return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe these reductions help you:

```
let x `op` y = if x > 2 then 0 else x + y

test                                       =>
foldr op 10 [0..]                          =>
0 `op` foldr op 10 [1..]                   =>
0 + foldr op 10 [1..]                      =>
0 + (1 `op` foldr op 10 [2..])             =>
0 + (1 + foldr op 10 [2..])                =>
0 + (1 + (2 `op` foldr op 10 [3..]))       =>
0 + (1 + (2 + foldr op 10 [3..]))          =>
0 + (1 + (2 + (3 `op` foldr op 10 [4..]))) =>
0 + (1 + (2 + 0))                          =>
0 + (1 + 2)                                =>
0 + 3                                      =>
3
```